# JQuery gives different values for window height each time i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

why does it return 671  when i first time load the page with google chrome but it returns different value when i relad the page

```
$("#online").css({height: $(window).height()-40-$("#head").height()});
```

Comment: Do the elements contain images etc ?

Comment: my problem is window.height gives different values when reloading

Comment: are you running this onready/onload event?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting up the layout on load and resize

```
$(window).on("load resize", function (e) {
    $("#online").css({height: $(window).height()-40-$("#head").height()});
});
```

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) goes into detail, in this case its a shorthand way of binding both window events at once

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/mhDNr/)

```
$("#online").css({ height: $(window).height() - 40 - $("#head").height() +'px' });
```